# Plotly line chart from pandas dataframe with multiple lines

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, plotly

This is my input dataframe:

```
labels  percentile_5  percentile_25  median  percentile_75  percentile_98
0       0            21             25      27             30             34
1       1            49             52      56             61             71
2       2            34             36      39             43             48
```

I have tried `transform` using the below code:

```
t = df.T.reset_index()
t.columns = t.iloc[0]
t = t.iloc[1:]
```

Output:

```
     labels         0   1   2
1   percentile_5    21  49  34
2   percentile_25   25  52  36
3   median          27  56  39
4   percentile_75   30  61  43
5   percentile_98   34  71  48
```

Using this I can create line chart with only one line.

```
fig = px.line(t, x="labels", y=0)
fig.show()
```

I am trying to plot like this, x-axis = labels, legend = 0,1,2

[image]

What are the changes I need to do in dataframe or
is there any easy way to plot using the first dataframe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly you don't have to do any changes. Just run:

```
fig = px.line(df, x='labels', y = df.columns)
```

[image]

This *should* be what you're looking for since you've specified `x=labels` and `legend = 0, 1, 2`.

#### Complete code

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px


df = pd.DataFrame({'labels': {1: 'percentile_5',
                              2: 'percentile_25',
                              3: 'median',
                              4: 'percentile_75',
                              5: 'percentile_98'},
                             '0': {1: 21, 2: 25, 3: 27, 4: 30, 5: 34},
                             '1': {1: 49, 2: 52, 3: 56, 4: 61, 5: 71},
                             '2': {1: 34, 2: 36, 3: 39, 4: 43, 5: 48}})
fig = px.line(df, x='labels', y = df.columns)
fig.show()
```